# Is it possible to load a new Applescript scripting addition whilst my script is running?

Tags: macos, applescript

According to various [documents](http://books.google.com/books?id=zQy4mgqIccsC&pg=PA363&lpg=PA363&dq="tell+me+to+event+ascrgdut"&source=bl&ots=scd1sOZMM-&sig=yFqEtoi6lZZYtjBsSL7A62udeFo&hl=en&ei=mMupS7vWMYKlsAbR453SBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CCYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=&f=false) and [discussions](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=927714) this used to be possible: you needed a block something like this in your script:

```
try
    tell me to «event ascrgdut»
end try
tell me to doTheFunkyNewThing
```

The event corresponds to hidden event with the undocumented C constant `kUpdateAEUT` (see [here](http://apple.doit.wisc.edu/mirrors/developer/Development_Kits/AppleScript/Headers/ASRegistry.h) for the declaration of the constant) which should force the scripting additions to be reloaded.

I've written a scripting addition and played around with this method of getting it to load but I have had no luck at all.  I can only make it load by starting my script after the extension has been installed.

Does anyone know if there is a way to make this work?  Has this functionality been disabled in more recent OS X releases?  I'm using OS X 10.6.2 FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `«event ascrgdut»`?